# Orthogonal derivative implies second derivative is null

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations, frechet-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be twice differentiable, such that $f'(x)$ is an orthogonal linear transformation for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $f''(x) = 0$, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
I've been struggling with this one, apparently it doesn't even use the inverse function theorem. Mi idea was to try and use the fact that $f'(x)$ preserves the norm, but that didn't work.

Comment: This post on MO should answer your question: https://mathoverflow.net/a/228969